# Entity Framework, Async and WPF threading. I've got so far but stuck on the threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, entity-framework-5, async-await

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction; I think I'm getting close but I've never done threading and keep getting stuck on syntax/concepts. The first part I believe is working, however I have a lovely WPF error regarding the owner of the thread. I know somehow I've got get at the thread with Dispatcher or BackGroundWorker but time is getting short - I'm hitting too many walls to solve it alone tonight. Here is the part I'm failing at:

```
 Private Sub FilterData(viewSource As CollectionViewSource, Filter As Expression(Of Func(Of person, Boolean)))
    _repository.GetFilteredPersons(Filter)

    viewSource.Source = _repository.FilteredPersons
End Sub
```

Now this next bit, I believe is either A) Working or B) fooling me as I've yet to prove it :).

```
 Public Property FilteredPersons() As ObservableCollection(Of Person)


    Public Async Sub GetFilteredPersons(criteria As Expression(Of Func(Of Person, Boolean)))
        FilteredPersons = Await FilterPersons(criteria)
    End Sub

    Private Async Function FilterPersons(criteria As Expression(Of Func(Of Person, Boolean))) As Task(Of ObservableCollection(Of Person))
        Return Await Run(Function()
                             Dim res = New ObservableCollection(Of Person)

                             _context = New caredocsSQLEntities
                             Dim test = _context.Persons.Where(criteria).Select(Function(o) New With { _
                                  .Person = o, _
                                  .events = o.events.Where(Function(e) e.eventDateTime >= Startdate And e.eventDateTime <= Enddate).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.eventDateTime)
                             })

                             For Each t In test
                                 res.Add(t.Person)
                             Next
                             Return res
                         End Function
        )
    End Function
```

Finally the exact error is `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it`.

I'm going to be tackling this again in a couple of hours once I've had chance to eat and read, again. However if anyone can tell me what the glaring silliness that I've not quite got my head around, I'd be rather grateful!!

The context is an Entity Framework 5 ObservableCollection with child navigation filtered properties-I don't think the code quite says it :).

Thank you :).

As requested, the exception I get. This occurrs in the repository code. The Thread stuff is a red herring.

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
HResult=-2146233079
Message=The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
Source=System.Data.Entity
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.EvaluateParameter(Object[] arguments)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at                   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() at SomeEntity.Models.PersonRepository._Closure$__2._Lambda$__7() in E:\Dropbox\Work         Experimental\SomeEntity - Copy\SomeEntity\Models\PersonRepository.vb:line 30
```

InnerException:

This is the entire exception and it occurs here:

```
  For Each t In test
          res.Add(t.Person)
  Next
```

I've been through the articles last night, whilst I understand it a little better now I'm still struggling to apply it to the repository class. This is usually a combination of syntax confusion and not quite getting it on my part. I've a feeling that I should be able to split out part of the operation in the getfiltered residents into an await task but haven't managed to figure it out just yet. Today's job - if entity framework can be used this way!

Comment: Your code is quite confusing and to me it looks like you don't know what you're doing. But it's hard to tell what exactly is the problem. Could you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Hi, there was an earlier comment who's links I've been reading for about 2 hrs. I'm going to hit the code again in the morning, after letting all the articles Ive been rereading sink in overnight. It is my first use of Async, true. I think I've a clearer understanding now thanks to the links from the earlier comments that lead to other links. Ill update this once I've gone back into the code. Thanks!